# spl-token-cli + missing token-2022 extensions

Tags: token-2022, spl-token-cli

I have a token-2022 mint using token-2022 metadata extension. The extensions display correctly on solana explorer (you can see the name, symbol, and uri along with the metadata pointer):

https://explorer.solana.com/address/HbxiDXQxBKMNJqDsTavQE7LVwrTR36wjV2EaYEqUw6qH

however, on spl-token (on v3.3.0), I get the following:

```
spl-token display HbxiDXQxBKMNJqDsTavQE7LVwrTR36wjV2EaYEqUw6qH

SPL Token Mint
  Address: HbxiDXQxBKMNJqDsTavQE7LVwrTR36wjV2EaYEqUw6qH
  Program: TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb
  Supply: 20999999999791637
  Decimals: 9
  Mint authority: (not set)
  Freeze authority: (not set)
```

Is there a trick to getting extensions to display correctly with spl-token client? Or is there an issue with the metadata? Would be odd given that multiple scanners display this one correctly.

Thanks guys - loving the new standard

Comment: You'll need to build the CLI from source if you want to see all the new extensions. We'll get a new release of the CLI out soon!